# How to include a custom field in the services list on WHMCS?

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

I'm using WHMCS 7.x and Smarty PHP is already enabled.

I want to show in the client area products (clientareaproducts.tpl) below the name of the product, a custom field which already exists and it's filled with an IP adress ( the smarty PHP code for that custom field is **{$service_custom_fields.4}** ) instead of **$service.domain**.

Below is the **clientareaproducts.tpl** file:

```
{include file="$template/includes/tablelist.tpl" tableName="ServicesList" filterColumn="3"}
<script type="text/javascript">
    {if $orderby == 'product'}
        table.order([0, '{$sort}'], [3, 'asc']);
    {elseif $orderby == 'amount' || $orderby == 'billingcycle'}
        table.order(1, '{$sort}');
    {elseif $orderby == 'nextduedate'}
        table.order(2, '{$sort}');
    {elseif $orderby == 'domainstatus'}
        table.order(3, '{$sort}');
    {/if}
    table.draw();
    jQuery('#tableLoading').addClass('hidden');
});
</script>
    <div class="table-container clearfix">
<table id="tableServicesList" class="table table-list hidden">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{$LANG.orderproduct}</th>
            <th>{$LANG.clientareaaddonpricing}</th>
            <th>{$LANG.clientareahostingnextduedate}</th>
            <th>{$LANG.clientareastatus}</th>
            <th class="responsive-edit-button" style="display: none;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {foreach key=num item=service from=$services}
            <tr onclick="clickableSafeRedirect(event, 'clientarea.php?action=productdetails&amp;id={$service.id}', false)">
                <td><strong>{$service.product}</strong>{if $service.domain}<br /><a href="http://{$service.domain}" target="_blank">{$service.domain}</a>{/if}</td>
                <td class="text-center" data-order="{$service.amountnum}">{$service.amount}<br />{$service.billingcycle}</td>
                <td class="text-center"><span class="hidden">{$service.normalisedNextDueDate}</span>{$service.nextduedate}</td>
                <td class="text-center"><span class="label status status-{$service.status|strtolower}">{$service.statustext}</span></td>
                <td class="responsive-edit-button" style="display: none;">
                    <a href="clientarea.php?action=productdetails&amp;id={$service.id}" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
                        {$LANG.manageproduct}
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {/foreach}
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="text-center" id="tableLoading">
    <p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> {$LANG.loading}</p>
</div>
```

I've tried replacing the following line:

```
 <td><strong>{$service.product}</strong>{if $service.domain}<br /><a href="http://{$service.domain}" target="_blank">{$service.domain}</a>{/if}</td>
```

with

```
 <td><strong>{$service.product}</strong>{if $service_custom_fields.4}<br /><a href="http://{$service_custom_fields.4}" target="_blank">{$service_custom_fields.4}</a>{/if}</td>
```

but unfourtunately, it doesn't work.

The smarty php code works on the email templates, but not here.

I've also tried with the following line by adding a domain to the product, but it doesn't show the custom field either.

```
 <td><strong>{$service.product}</strong>{if $service.domain}<br /><a href="http://{$service_custom_fields.4}" target="_blank">{$service_custom_fields.4}</a>{/if}</td>
```

I did that because i thought *domainstatus*

```
{elseif $orderby == 'domainstatus'}
```

would be setted to false if the domain was empty and by adding a domain, it would then be setted to true, and it would show the custom field, but it doesn't work.

I'd really appreciate if someone could please help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

WHMCS doesn't populate the custom fields for the services in this page. 
In general you can check what is available for you by using smarty function `debug_print_var` inside the tpl file:

```
{$service|@debug_print_var}
```

Now, you need to take care of populating the custom field you want. This can be done using hooks.

The hook [ClientAreaPageProductsServices](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/client-area-interface/#clientareapageproductsservices) will be called when clientareaproducts page is visited, and it presents all template variables as function parameter `$vars`.

We're going to loop through `$vars['services']` and query custom field values from Db and pass them as separate variable that you can use in tpl file:

1- Create file: `includes/hooks/service_customfields.php` and add the following code to it:

```
<?php
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule as DB;
if (!defined("WHMCS")) {
    die("This file cannot be accessed directly");
}

add_hook('ClientAreaPageProductsServices', 1, function($vars) {

    $fieldId = 4; //Custom field id
    if (isset($vars['services'])) {
        $csVals = [];
        foreach ($vars['services'] as $service) {

            $fieldVal = '';
            $data = DB::table('tblcustomfieldsvalues AS t1')
            ->leftJoin('tblcustomfields AS t2', 't1.fieldid', '=', 't2.id')
            ->select('t1.value')
            ->where('t2.id', $fieldId)->where('t2.type', 'product')->where('t1.relid', $service['id'])
            ->first();
            if (!is_null($data)) {
                $fieldVal = $data->value;
            }
            $csVals[$service['id']] = $fieldVal;

        }

        return ['customFields' => $csVals];
    }
});
```

2- In `clientareaproducts.tpl` use `{$customFields[$service.id]}` to output custom field value.

Note: code is querying custom field value using this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues AS t1
LEFT JOIN tblcustomfields AS t2 ON t1.fieldid = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = 2 #Field id
AND t2.type = 'product' 
AND t1.relid = 9 #service id
```

Comment: Hello, first of all, thanks for your reply. I've added the code to the hooks section and replaced with `{$customFields[$service.id]}` inside the .tpl file but it doesn't work, it's not showing the IP adress below the product name. Maybe it has something to do with this line `{elseif $orderby == 'domainstatus'}` being disabled if there's no domain configured?

Comment: Try not to add it inside if, add it right after {$service.product} for now, just to make sure it is working.